# Starting MVVM in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I've been working in WPF but no with MVVM. For various reasons i'm going to start my application over and try and follow MVVM.

I'm starting to get the gist of MVVM but I am still unsure about a number of things.

In my original program I had a few UserControls, one for instance was a custom image control this was made up of a UserControl with a Grid inside and then in the Grid there was an Image Control with ContextMenu.

So if I wanted to recreate this but following best practice for MVVM would I still use a UserControl or would I split this up?

Any advice on how to go about this would be appreciated..

Many Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but this cannot easily be answered. It depends on your requirements, the size of your project as well as the final utilization. Your approach might be a good one in your case. In another case it might be better to avoid `UserControls`. Difficuilt to tell, without knowing any details, because `UserControls` and `MVVM` don't bite each other. I suggest that you clarify your question.

Comment: `UserControl`s are absolutely fine to use in a MVVM pattern. You could either create a view model for each of them, or use the view model of the parent `Window` or `UserControl` by using the following binding: `UserControl.DataContext="{Binding}"` This will set the same view model for the `UserControl` as the parent control.